# Is it possible to force .NET JIT to recompile a method to a higher tier?

Tags: .net, clr, jit

I know that I can use `RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod` to JIT-compile a .NET method.
In my understanding in tiered compilation model this would give me Tier 0.

Is there something I can use to force-recompile this method to Tier 1?

Comment: You can't assume that you'll get 0 or that the method won't be upgraded.  The best place to ask for features [is here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues).  Be sure to explain why you need it.

Comment: @andrey-shchekin, could you find the answer to your question?